# new dkim config -> opendkim-testkey: record not found

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, dkim

I am trying to set up dkim and I cannot get it to work or test properly, and I get the following error:

```
opendkim-testkey -vvvv -d domain.com -s default
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.domain.com'
opendkim-testkey: 'default._domainkey.domain.com' record not found
```

I tried to rename to key to a bunch of different possibilities, nah-dah:

mlr01 keys # ls

```
default                                default.private  _domainkey.domain.com
default._domainkey.domain.com  default.txt      domain.com
```

I have the following record in my bind dns zone file

```
default._domainkey      IN      TXT     ( "v=DKIM1; k=rsa; "
          "p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC/9PDXdenz1TVY5lcdnsx2x+0GEeaLviGkZmnNW+7CCpNcRjj1ulO4CcRWgqCUynJUmHj2ma0HLAsHUC7NZdi0HmagG5HSYA+K8nuB8/SdMPoF+FFG5ccOAwTh7flXPTepwJmJgeN0DrtVzDaWHGs+Y+S9UBPZRR7GfKHb1WIdEwIDAQAB" )  ; ----- DKIM key default for domain.com
```

dns is error free except for dkim

here is my config:

mlr01 keys # cat ../opendkim.conf

```
LogWhy                 yes
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           yes

Canonicalization        relaxed/simple

Domain                  domain.com
#KeyFile                        /etc/opendkim/keys/default.private

Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
ReportAddress           postmaster@domain.com
SendReports             yes

## Hosts to sign email for - 127.0.0.1 is default
## See the OPERATION section of opendkim(8) for more information
#
# InternalHosts         192.168.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12

## For secondary mailservers - indicates not to sign or verify messages
## from these hosts
#
# PeerList              X.X.X.X

PidFile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid

Mode                    sv
#Selector                mydkim
Selector                default
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
LogWhy                  yes
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256
UserID                  milter:milter
UMask                   002
```

Comment: can you provide `ls -la` output on the key directory? Also, what does the log say?

Comment: @aif    keys # ls -la
https://bpaste.net/show/8d79f185b3a1  I tried milter:milter and root:root. also 770 and 640 for all files in opendkim

Comment: Ensure that the user "milter" can actually fetch the keys, because right now, it should not be able to. Try `su - milter; cd /; cat /etc/opendkim/keys/default._domainkey.domain.com` for instance.

Comment: Yes, it works now. there was junk in my reverse dns  ->    # su - milter; cd /; cat /etc/opendkim/keys/default._domainkey.drpedroazevedo.com
This account is currently not available.
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAK

Comment: I recommend you follow this tutorial:
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setting-up-dkim-and-spf